# Display on particular category and manage by admin

Tags: wordpress

I want to make calculator should be display on particular category. I have added a code for flag if display flag is on then show if not then hide. Basically its hide show based on product belongs to which category. For example automobile then calculate fule if fruit then should not display.

```
/*
 * Display input on single product page
 * @return html
 */
function wallc_custom_option(){

    global $post;


    // when its display
    if($display_flag){

    // Logic of calling calculator
    $wall_width_value = isset( $_POST['wall_width_value'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wall_width_value'] ) : '';
    $wall_height_value = isset( $_POST['wall_height_value'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wall_height_value'] ) : '';
    printf( '<div class="rollcalculator">');
   ?>
   <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" >Wall width</label>
    <input  class="form-control control-label" id="wall_width_value" name="wall_width_value"  />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" >Wall height</label>
        <input  class="form-control control-label"  id="wall_height_value" name="wall_height_value" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> <p><button id="estimateRole" class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="myFunction()">Estimate number of rolls</button></p></div>
<?php
    global $product;

    $dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();

    if ( ! empty( $dimensions ) ) {
        // all in cm
    $height= $product->get_height();
    $width=$product->get_width();
    $length=$product->get_length();

    //  CONVERT TO METER
    $pattern_height= $height/100;
    $pattern_width= $width/100;
    $pattern_repeat= $length/100;


    echo '<input type="hidden" id="pattern_height" value="'.$pattern_height.'" />';

    echo '<input type="hidden" id="pattern_width" value="'.$pattern_width.'"/>';

    echo '<input type="hidden" id="pattern_repeat" value="'.$pattern_repeat.'"/>';
    echo '<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" >Roll Required</label><label class="form-control" id="totalRole"></label></div>';


    //correct
   // $WALL_AREA = ceil(($wall_width_value+$pattern_height) * $wall_height_value);    
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(){

          }
    </script>

    <?php 


    }
}


}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'wallc_custom_option', 9 );
```

Comment: u should add a better description

Comment: all code is ready that I have posted I just need a flag which I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get terms and fetch a details based on that change a display flag if find category then break loop and execute rest of code.

```
   /*
 * Display input on single product page
 * @return html
 */
function wallc_custom_option(){

    global $post;

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    $display_flag=false;
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
    {       
            $wh_meta_checkbox = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'wh_meta_checkbox', true);
            if($wh_meta_checkbox == 'on'){
                $display_flag=true;
                break;
            }

    }

    // when its display
    if($display_flag){

    // Logic of calling calculator
    $wall_width_value = isset( $_POST['wall_width_value'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wall_width_value'] ) : '';
    $wall_height_value = isset( $_POST['wall_height_value'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wall_height_value'] ) : '';
    printf( '<div class="rollcalculator">');
   ?>
   <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" >Wall width</label>
    <input  class="form-control control-label" id="wall_width_value" name="wall_width_value"  />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" >Wall height</label>
        <input  class="form-control control-label"  id="wall_height_value" name="wall_height_value" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> <p><button id="estimateRole" class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="myFunction()">Estimate number of rolls</button></p></div>
<?php
    global $product;

    $dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();

    if ( ! empty( $dimensions ) ) {
        // all in cm
    $height= $product->get_height();
    $width=$product->get_width();
    $length=$product->get_length();

    //  CONVERT TO METER
    $pattern_height= $height/100;
    $pattern_width= $width/100;
    $pattern_repeat= $length/100;


    echo '<input type="hidden" id="pattern_height" value="'.$pattern_height.'" />';

    echo '<input type="hidden" id="pattern_width" value="'.$pattern_width.'"/>';

    echo '<input type="hidden" id="pattern_repeat" value="'.$pattern_repeat.'"/>';
    echo '<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" >Roll Required</label><label class="form-control" id="totalRole"></label></div>';


    //correct
   // $WALL_AREA = ceil(($wall_width_value+$pattern_height) * $wall_height_value);    
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(){

          // wall input
          wall_width_value=Number($("#wall_width_value").val());
          wall_height_value=Number($("#wall_height_value").val());

          // Product dimensions

          pattern_height=Number($("#pattern_height").val());
          pattern_width=Number($("#pattern_width").val());
          pattern_repeat=Number($("#pattern_repeat").val());
          WALL_AREA = Math.ceil((wall_width_value+pattern_height) * wall_height_value);  

          wall_width_value_meter=wall_width_value/100;
         pattern_width_meter=pattern_width;

          PATTERN_AREA = (pattern_width * pattern_repeat) ;

          totalRole=Math.ceil(WALL_AREA/PATTERN_AREA);

            $("#totalRole").text(totalRole);
        }
    </script>

    <?php 


    }
}


}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'wallc_custom_option', 9 );
```